# how to update partial document of an array

Tags: mongodb

i have a person document, that have list of pets:

```
{
  "personId": "kjadfh97r0",
  "pets": [
    {
      "petId": "dfjkh32476",
      "name": "kitty",
      "kind": "cat"
    },
    {
      "petId": "askdjfh2794857",
      "name": "rexy",
      "kind": "dog"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find certain pen inside of certain person and update just some fields, so I did something like:

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { "personId": "kjadfh97r0", "pets.petId": "dfjkh32476" },
    update: {"$set":{"pets.$":{"kind":"tiger"}}}
})
```

but what happens to me is that the whole document is replaced with `"kind":"tiger"`, and I just wanted to update the "kind" field any keep the rest.

Comment: did you read the docs ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify entire path for `$set` when you update nested document using [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/index.html#update-documents-in-an-array), otherwise the document will be replaced:

```
db.people.findAndModify({
   query: { "personId": "kjadfh97r0", "pets.petId": "dfjkh32476" },
   update: { $set: {"pets.$.kind": "tiger"} }
})
```